# Using cmake to pre-validate or post-validate specific files

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have a scenario where I need to process a header file. I can do it either pre or post build.

I have a simple POST_BUILD step to execute a script.

```
add_custom_command(TARGET abc
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND powershell /path/to/my_script.ps1
        )
```

The script will do some validation either pass or fail. How can I fail cmake if I find an issue?

Should I be using `ctest_run_script` instead or is there another clever way of doing it.

Ideally I should be running this action only when `my_header.h` has changed.

Thanks in advance, cmake newbie

Comment: Doing this as pre- or post-build will both be *after* CMake completes. The *build* term, in this case, refers to compiling your libraries/executables (e.g. running `make`). If you want this to validate the header *during* the CMake configure-stage, you should use `execute_process`.

Comment: If I do that then it wouldnt run again if the header file was changed. This is why I was thinking of doing it at build time. In case it matters, I am using ninja for build.